# Spark-error when trying to read json file from local FS

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run a basic scala-spark example:

```
object LoadJsonWithSparkSQL{
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
     val master = "local"
     val inputFile = "/path/to/my/local/file"    
     val warehouseLocation = "/path/to/spark-warehouse"

     val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.
         master(master)
        .appName("LoadJsonWithSparkSQL")
        .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
        .getOrCreate()

    val input = sparkSession.read.json(inputFile)
    input.printSchema()
    sparkSession.stop()
```

A spark session is created. While trying to read the json file I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus.isDirectory()Z
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ListingFileCatalog.scala:129)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ListingFileCatalog.scala:116)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(ListingFileCatalog.scala:116)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog$$anonfun$1.apply(ListingFileCatalog.scala:102)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog.listLeafFiles(ListingFileCatalog.scala:102)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog.refresh(ListingFileCatalog.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ListingFileCatalog.<init>(ListingFileCatalog.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:379)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:149)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:249)
at LoadJsonWithSparkSQL$.main(LoadJsonWithSparkSQL.scala:50)
at LoadJsonWithSparkSQL.main(LoadJsonWithSparkSQL.scala) 17/07/26 17:13:37 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Any ideas how to fix that?

My set-up is:

spark: 2.0.0

scala: 2.10

All files are on my local FS.

Comment: have you prefixed you path with file:// ?

Comment: Yeah. I tried both with and w-out "file:///"

Comment: what's the error you are getting if you put `file://` in front?

Comment: With two "/" I get  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: file://path/to/my/local/file ....

Comment: @a.dalevskaya you have to give file path. I guess you are giving a directory path .

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan, I give "/path/to/my/local/file", not to a directory ;)

Comment: @a.dalevskaya --  did your issue resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can go with two options 
sc.textFile("file:///path to the file/"). if it is textfile.
otherwise if its Json file then you can try with dataframes
df = sqlContext.read.json("file")
Please try with create dataframe. This DF is very easy to explore on data.

Comment: I've tried        val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.json(inputFile). Still having the same error.